# CSS viewport size is different

Tags: css, viewport, responsive

I have a responsive page with that in head

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

And i have a CSS rule which does the following:

```
@media screen and (min-width:998px) { 
   .navbar-nav { background-color:red; }
}
```

But this CSS rule is already triggered when my browser has a width of 983px which i logged with jQuery.. $(window).width(); i was wondering if that's maybe a bug and i opened: http://viewportsizes.com/mine/ to check what my current viewport size is... On that page it's 915px width. When i change the tab in my Browser back to my page where i have the log in Firebug i can see that my viewport on that page is 983 width... How can it be that the viewport is different on that page, and the css rules are triggered not when i expect it...

Comment: Are there scrollbars when you're viewing it?

Comment: `$(window).width()` doesn't count the width of your scrollbar, but that does count for the total width of the viewport.  jQuery is funky that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the jQuery function

```
$(window).width()
```

does not account for scrollbars. Here is a simple jsFiddle that demonstrates this (grow and shrink the browser to see the width change) :

https://jsfiddle.net/iamnottony/14pyfg3r/7/

The height of the div causes a scrollbar. This causes the background to turn red at 981px (because the width of the window (981px) plus the width of the scrollbar is 998px)

If you remove the second .navbar-nav css rule

```
.navbar-nav{
  height: 1000px;
}
```

you will see that the background color becomes red at 998px (the behavior you were originally expecting)